# What are patterns you could use with prototype inheritance that you cannot with class?

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance

Everyone seems to generally agree that prototype inheritance is simpler and more flexible than class inheritance. What I have not seen in the literature that I've read is very many examples of things that you can do with prototype inheritance that you cannot with classical. So I pose a simple question:

What are some patterns that you can use with prototype inheritance that you cannot with class inheritance and what is the guidance you would give as far when/if to use it?

Comment: This should probably be moved to programmers.stackexchange.

Comment: @Paul: Why? This isn't a business guidance/best practice question, more theoretical. At least, that's how I read it.

Comment: Isn't that what Programmers is about? SO is about help, Programmers is about theoretical stuff (among other things).

Comment: This isn't theoretical, this is about best-practices, Would asking when to use factory vs. adapter be theoretical too?

Comment: (+1) Not a fan of prototype inheritance, but your question is worthly. Actually, I like to call O.O.P. as Object & Class Oriented Programming (O.C.O.P.)

Comment: "Best-practice", voted to close and move to Programmers.

Comment: I'd like to see some better answers here: Right now there are 3 answers that are really about dynamism, and one about definitions. No actual examples of patterns using prototypal inheritance that can't be done with classes.

Comment: I'm with @Sean. Any Javascripts experts that can provide some good answers?

Answer (score 2):

One difference (perhaps at least conceptually) is that class inheritance implies that the child IS-A type of the parent. Prototype inheritance makes no such implication; a mammal is a prototype for a cat (the Merriam-Webster definition says this means it's a "pattern for"), but nothing else. A cat is free remove/add/change behaviors as it sees fit.

Comment: Actually, it's incorrect to say that class inheritance implies an "is-a", I believe I first heard this explained by Bob Martin during a Herding Code episode. A Square "is a" Rectangle but Square : Rectangle breaks the Liskov Substitution Principle since changing Height will change Width and this is not expected behavior if you're working with a Rectangle. I believe I've heard that the 'is-a' terminology is a leaky metaphor coming from a some project in the AI community in the 70s. http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/lsp.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'll add one, use the fact that prototype links are live to monkey-patch methods for a whole class of objects:

```
var Cat = function(catName) {
    this.catName = catName;
};
Cat.prototype.meow = function() {
    console.log(this.catName+" says meow");
}
var mittens = new Cat("Mittens");
var whiskers = new Cat("Whiskers");
mittens.meow(); // "Mittens says meow"
whiskers.meow(); // "Whiskers says meow"

// All cats are now angry
Cat.prototype.meow = function() {
    console.log(this.catName+" says hissssss");
}
mittens.meow(); // "Mittens says hissssss"
whiskers.meow(); // "Whiskers says hissssss"
```

This would be useful if you have objects that suddenly need to start acting in a completely different yet consistent manner in response to some sort of global event.  Maybe for something like:

- Themes and skinning
- Whether a page is functioning in "online mode" or "offline mode" (while online all queries are stored/retrieved via ajax, while offline queries redirect to browser storage)

Comment: I'm only asking out of ignorance, but don't you get this benefit because the definition is looked up at runtime? I mean, you could do this with class inheritance if you could lookup/change the definition of the method at runtime as well, right?

Comment: Yeah, this has much more to do with dynamic languages than prototyping. Python, Ruby, Smalltalk, and others can do all of the above.

Comment: @Esteban: Correct. Java and most other old OO languages come from a time when lookup was expensive, so types are immutable. Most modern scripting languages have dynamic types. JavaScript and Python even allow to add methods to instances, so each instance gets its own methods.

Comment: That's a good point, if you consider Ruby's ability to include and exclude mixins at runtime I'm having a tough time thinking of someonthing that you can do on one model and not the other.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no real class inheritance in JavaScript, you will probably never find any literature explaining what you can't do with classic class inheritance in JavaScript, unless you compare it with class inheritance in other languages.

So I'll consider your question as if you meant:

> What are some patterns that you can use with JavaScript prototype inheritance that you cannot do with class inheritance in languages that support it?

R= In general, most object oriented languages that are based in Class Inheritance produce objects that have a rigid structure, they will always have the same methods and properties during their life and all the objects of the same classes will have the same structure.

So, in general, the patterns you can apply with a prototype based language that can't be implemented with a class inheritance language are the ones that depend on:

- Add or remove methods or properties to objects, on the fly

*This is so well supported in JavaScript due to it's dynamic an cross domain collaborative nature. Sometimes you need to load external scripts from other websites but need to add new functionalities without being able to change the source-code from these external libraries.

Comment: Come to think of it, are there are any languages that have good support for *both* types of inheritance?

Comment: Yes. Ate least PHP let's you do that with a technique called [overloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php).
Of course PHP is not as dynamic as JavaScript, but it's a real world example of class inheritance language with some sort of behavior you only encounter in prototype language.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I agree with your premise, but the major benefit of prototype based inheritance is that it allows runtime assignment of properties and methods on all members of the class, even when there are already instances of that class.

The theorist in me actually cringes at some of those implications. Imagine debugging something where you have no idea which piece of code has completely re-defined your class structure. It is beyond daunting.

But, I will say, that it has proven useful:

Once, when I was working in ActionScript 2 (not for the faint of heart as it is almost a non-deterministic language) inside of an ActionScript 3 container. An unknown side-effect of this problem is that it eliminates the idea of memory levels (something essential to my company's legacy code). I was able to add the line: `MovieClip.prototype._level0 = _root;` and it solved the problem.

To counter my above argument, the fact that you can modify all instances after the fact does provide you with a certain amount of power in situations where you do not have access to the original code base (like the example), but I see no major benefit beyond that.

Comment: I think your complaint condemns all dynamic languages with strong metaprogramming abilities. Ruby, Python, etc. Can't really say I've had a tremendous amount of difficulty debugging them (or JS for that matter as long as there is a test suite)