# The difference between a class-based language (like Java or Python) and a prototype-based language (like Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, python, class, prototype

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [prototype based vs. class based inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816071/prototype-based-vs-class-based-inheritance)

This question came up at work the other day - what's the difference between a class-based language like Python, and a prototype-based language like Javascript? Aside from differing approches, both ways seem very similar and we struggled to find something that a class-based language could do that a prototype-based language couldn't, or vice-versa.

Can anybody elaborate or go into any detail on how they differ fundamentally?

I haven't found much online about the differences, just sites that show you how to accomplish one with the other (such as this: [Simulating classes with prototypes in JavaScript](http://unspecified.wordpress.com/2011/06/05/simulating-classes-with-prototypes-in-javascript/))

Any enlightenment appreciated!

Comment: Might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/816071/prototype-based-vs-class-based-inheritance

Comment: JavaScript doesn't implement interfaces, nor can it natively enforce it. This limits things like [SPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_provider_interface).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707176/demonstrating-javascript-inheritance-benefits-in-relation-to-a-class-based-model, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6266690/what-are-patterns-you-could-use-with-prototype-inheritance-that-you-cannot-with

Comment: knowing JavaScript's history will explain why it's prototypal at the same time class-based.

Comment: @Petah: That is actually more of a dynamic vs static typing thing. Dynamic class-based languages also have the same "problem".

Comment: @Joseph Eich stated that he'd been in big trouble if he'd added classes to Javascript; after all it's initial design was for it to be Java's dumb little brother which shouldn't be used for serious programs (hey don't look at me, I'm roughly quoting; that's from coders at work). One problem that should be noted is the pretty problematic fact of optimizing prototype based approaches..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you're familiar with the actual languages, so you know what the difference is, right? I guess you're asking about the differences at a deeper, maybe more "philosophical", level.

Class-based languages tend to work from the top down, general to particular. The classic example would be where you define a 'Vehicle' class, and then subclasses like 'Car', 'Train'.

A prototype-based language would instead tend to start with the particular, in fact start with an instance of the particular and modify that.

I like this: http://steve-yegge.blogspot.ie/2008/10/universal-design-pattern.html

In the end it's not a question of if you can do inheritance in JS or whether there is something that you can do in one language but not the other. It's a deep difference in their ways of approaching problem solving. For a particular problem a good idiomatic solution that made best use of the language's features would probably be quite different in a prototype-based language from one in a class-based language.

Comment: In a prototype language you can start from a particular and then generalize but you can start general and go particular as well.  In class-based languages there is less flexibility [however, Python & Ruby & Smalltalk all allow their classes to have the fexibility of prototype languages through stuff like __getattr__, method_missing, class decorators, open classes, changing types of objects, adding methods to objects, deleting methods from classes, etc...]

Answer (score 6):

Check out [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model#Class-Based_vs._Prototype-Based_Language). It is a detailed article discussing the differences between class-based and prototype-based languages.

Copy of the table summarizing the differences:

### Class-based (Java)

- Class and instance are distinct entities.
- Define a class with a class definition; instantiate a class with constructor methods.
- Create a single object with the new operator.
- Construct an object hierarchy by using class definitions to define subclasses of existing classes.
- Inherit properties by following the class chain.
- Class definition specifies all properties of all instances of a class. Cannot add properties dynamically at run time.

### Prototype-based (JavaScript)

- All objects are instances.
- Define and create a set of objects with constructor functions.
- Same.
- Construct an object hierarchy by assigning an object as the prototype associated with a constructor function.
- Inherit properties by following the prototype chain.
- Constructor function or prototype specifies an initial set of properties. Can add or remove properties dynamically to individual objects or to the entire set of objects.

Comment: You really could've copied the tables. Formatting text as pixel data was never a good idea.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, quite helpful. But Python differs from Java in the way that classes are also first-class objects, and you can also add properties dynamically at run time - so how does this differ from Javascript's prototype approach?

Comment: @Bergi - SO doesn't even allow table markup. I personally like the images better than trying to mock a table in text.

Comment: Of course, in more "pure" OO languages, classes are themselves objects. For instance, Python has "classes", but you can assign properties dynamically (well, unless it's a built-in or  extension class or `__slots__` is being used), and Python classes are, for the most part, themselves instances of class `type`. So there's a bit of a spectrum, so to speak.

Comment: @Ben - I've never used Python, but you can also add properties dynamically to Javascript objects.

Comment: @JAB - that's my question! How does Python's classes-as-objects approach differ to Javascript's prototype approach?

Comment: @jeff - yes, which you can do in Python too, so I guess I should have worded my question better. How does Python's particular approach differ? (as opposed to Java, which is clearly quite different)

Comment: @Ben - I'm afraid I don't know, as I've never used Python. I bet that if you google "Differences between Python and Javascript," you'll find something on that, though.

Comment: @Ben Well it's the old [metaclass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaclass) concept, nothing new there. Lots of languages have it and as I understand it the concept is much more prevalent in Ruby (never written a single line in it, so that's hearsay). The "inventor" of the concept would be smalltalk as usual though.

Comment: @Voo I understand that it's because of metaclasses, but what I'm asking is how that's different to prototypes?

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript guide of MDN has some good points, take a look: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model

Answer (score 0):

Well, they're both (usually) Turning Complete.  :)

Classes are about enforcing encapsulation, at the expense of some (or a lot of) run-time extensibility.  Prototypes encourage encapsulation and allow almost unlimited run-time extension.

Seriously, prototype-based OO makes it very easy -- some would say dangerously easy -- to dynamically extend/derive from an object.  Prototype languages therefore do not coexist easily with static typing.  So if you like how compilers catch type errors, you will almost certainly be excluding prototype-based languages.

There's actually a very good discussion here: http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/12/understanding-prototypes-in-javascript/ although there are others which are just as good I liked that one.

Comment: I don't think the inheritance model and the type system are mutually dependent.